# Equivalence of Norms in $R[X]$ (Need to understand a Solution)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, normed-spaces

Could you explain to me clearly (as if I was new to the concept of norm equivalence) the solution, please?

**Problem :** Let $E = R[X]$. We define on $E$ vector space three norms, with $$P=\sum_{i=0}^p a_{i}X^i :$$
$$N_{1}(P) = \sum_{i=0}^p a_{i}$$
$$N_{2}(P) = (\sum_{i=0}^p |a_{i}|²)^{1/2}$$
$$N_{∞}(P) = max|a_{i}|$$

**Solution :** Suppose $N_{1}(P)\leq KN_{∞}(P)$. Let us take $P_{n} = 1 + X + ... + X^n$, then, $N_{1}(P_{n}) = n+1\leq K$, which is impossible for $n$ getting bigger.

If $N_{2}(P_{n})\leq KN_{∞}$ for the same polynomial $P_{n}$, we have $N_{2}(P_{n})=\sqrt{n+1} \leq K$ which is still impossible.
Finally the same sequence of polynomials, and the same reasoning, show that $N_{1}(P_{n})\leq KN_{2}(P_{n})$ is also impossible.

Notice that the proof this norms aren't equivalents is based on the fact that $R[X]$ is of infinite dimension. *End of the solution.*

Comment: Two norms are equivalent if they generate the same topology.  This happens when one norm can be bound in between a scalar copy of the other norm on both high and low end, because then open sets are the same (As you can fit open balls around the same interior points,  just of different sizes)

Comment: Do you know the definition of norm equivalence? And I recommend to change the title into "Nonequivalence of norms ..."

Comment: Do nor write $X=R[X]$. You are using $X$ for two different things.